# (non-touch) iPhone gesture recognition

Tags: iphone, arduino, ethernet, gesture-recognition, gesture

I am about to start on a huge new project which will rely on the use of an Arduino connected to third party electronics (in this case an electromyography board I have already built).

I have a good idea of how to transmit data between the Arduino and the iPhone or iPad using protocols like [OSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) and an Ethernet shield.

What I am hoping to achieve is to effectively analyse an incoming analog signal and recognise the gestures employed to create that signal. So what I am essentially talking about is waveform analysis, whether it is on the iPhone side or on the Arduino side. Are there any libraries or previous methods of analysing or recognising gestures? This is going to be a large research project, so I am really looking for a push in the right direction.

This, I understand, might be a vague question so if anybody wants me to shed some light on the matter I will be more than happy.

Comment: That sounds nutty. Good luck.

Comment: ha.. thanks?... It might sound a bit out there, but using an arduino you can easily communicate to an iOS device, meaning that if a good gesture library existed, we could effectively open mobile device use up to a far greater number of people, particularly those who are incapable of using small touch screen interfaces, i.e. people whom suffer from disabilities or debilitating illnesses.